# Remote emacs daemon setup?

Tags: emacs-daemon

I've got a "shell account" on a distant server and I've done a successful local user setup of Emacs 25. Now I'd like to have a bash alias that will start an Emacs daemon and give me (a) client(s) to work with. I've seen different advice on this. Can't seem to find the definite answer.

Comment: Show us the "difference advice" that you've seen.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570451/how-to-start-emacs-server-only-if-it-is-not-started

Comment: I use `emacsclient -a '' -c` now -- on my home computer (Ubuntu) to start Emacs. Didn't realize it would work in a `-nw` realm as well. . . .

Comment: As far as "different advice" is concerned, just look at the link after yours from Nisba. Could you figure out who is right? Everyone is saying slightly different things....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mjwall has, in my opinion, a quite clean setup.

http://mjwall.com/blog/2013/10/04/how-i-use-emacs/

Comment: Link-only answers are depreciated. Please add the essential information that answers the question here.